# Quantiles calculation in Pyspark MLib

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to find out quantiles for each column on the table for various firms using spark 1.6

I have around 5000 entries in firm_list and 300 entries in `attr_lst`. Number of records in table is around 200000.

I am using 10 executors each with 16gb memory.

Currently it is taking around 1 second for each quantile calculation and 2 mins for whole transformation. with this pace, it will run around 10000 Mins for 5000 firms.

Please let me know how can I optimize the performance.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from src.utils import sql_service, apa_constant as constant,file_io_service                          
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonicallyIncreasingId
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,col,broadcast
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import *
from concurrent.futures import *
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark
import numpy as np

def generate_quantile_reports(spark_context,hive_context,log,attribute_type,**kwargs): 

    sql = """describe {}.apa_all_attrs_consortium""".format(kwargs['sem_db'])
    op = hive_context.sql(sql)
    res = op.withColumn("ordinal_position",monotonicallyIncreasingId())
    res.registerTempTable('attribs')

    attr_lst = hive_context.sql("""select col_name from attribs where ordinal_position > 24 AND col_name not like '%vehicle%' AND col_name not like'%cluster_num%' AND col_name not like '%value_seg%' order by ordinal_position""").collect()

    sql = """select distinct firm_id, firm_name from {}.apa_all_attrs_consortium where ud_rep = 1 and lower(channel) not in ('ria','clearing') order by firm_id limit 5 """.format(kwargs['sem_db'])
    dat = hive_context.sql(sql)
    firm_list = dat.collect()
    sql = """select entity_id, cast(firm_id as double), %s from %s.apa_all_attrs_consortium where ud_rep = 1 and lower(channel) not in ('ria','clearing') cluster by entity_id""" % (", ".join("cast(" + str(attr.col_name) + " as double)" for attr in attr_lst), kwargs['sem_db'])

    df = hive_context.sql(sql)
    qrtl_list = []
    df.cache()
    df.count()
    counter = 0
    for (fm,fnm) in firm_list:
      df2 = df[df.firm_id == fm]
      df2 = df2.replace(0, np.nan)
      df_main = df2.drop('firm_id')
      counter += 1
      colNames = []
      quartileList = []
      bucketizerList = []
      for var in attr_lst:
          colNames.append(var.col_name)
      jdf = df2._jdf
      bindt = spark_context._jvm.com.dstsystems.apa.util.DFQuantileFunction.approxQuantile(jdf,colNames,[0.0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0],0.0)
      for i in range(len(bindt)):            
        quartile = sorted(list(set(list(bindt[i]))))
        quartile = [-float("inf")] + quartile
        quartile.insert(len(quartile),float("inf"))
        quartile.insert(len(quartile),float("NaN"))
        df_main = df_main.filter(df_main[colNames[i]].isNotNull())
        bucketizerList.append(Bucketizer().setInputCol(colNames[i]).setOutputCol("{}_quantile".format(colNames[i])).setSplits(quartile))
      path = " {}/tmpPqtDir/apa_team_broker_quartiles".format(kwargs['semzone_path'])
      qrtl_list.append(Pipeline(stages=bucketizerList).fit(df_main).transform(df_main))
    finalDF = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, qrtl_list)
    finalDF.repartition(200).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").parquet(path)
    df.unpersist()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The indentation of your code is broken. You can paste your code from an editor and then either use ["code fences"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/312087) or select it and press Ctrl+K to have it formatted for you.

Comment: @AlexV : Thanks for the suggestion, corrected the indentation.